# jQuery "on" function event map optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

**CODE I:**

```
$searchBoxParent.on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().find(".hlight").removeClass('hlight');
        $this.addClass("hlight");
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().find(".hlight").removeClass('hlight');
    },
    click: function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $searchBox.val($this.text()).focus();
        setCurrentlySearchedText();
        deleteSuggestionsDiv();
    }
},"#searchSuggest div");
```

**CODE II:**
In the above code i want to reduce starting two common statement of mouseover & mouseout functions into one block to reduce redundancy. To achieve this i added a function -

```
mouseMovement: function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().find(".hlight").removeClass('hlight');
}
```

and changed my mouseover by -

```
mouseover: function() {
    this.mouseMovement;
    $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("hlight");
}
```

and mouseout by -

```
mouseover: function() {
    this.mouseMovement;
}
```

**Inference:**
I am pretty much confused, as the second case is reducing redundancy to certain level but `$this = $(this);` is very redundant. Is it possible to declare global for "on" function instead of individual function scope? Also i wanna know your views whether first code is just fine or second one..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the mouseover event as one line:

```
$(this).addClass('hlight').siblings('.hlight').removeClass('hlight');
```

Or like this:

```
$(this).addClass('hlight').parent().find('.hlight').not(this).removeClass('hlight');
```

Same with mouseout:

```
$(this).siblings('.hlight').removeClass('hlight');
```

I don't think the code in your mouseout is necessary, as only one element will have the class. You should be able to get by with just using:

```
$(this).removeClass('hlight');
```

In either case, this removes your redundancies, as you are a) not storing a reference to `this`, and b) only accessing it once; jQuery chains always return a reference to the object that is acted upon.

Note, you can't globally scope `this`, as it changes each time jQuery acts upon an element. In the instance of your code examples, I would say that the execution performance differences are probably neglible. Creating a variable reference to `this` is faster, because `$(this)` has to access the DOM and locate the element each time it is called. If you are going to be using `$(this)` in multiple statements (not chained), then it is more efficient to grab the reference and manipulate around that.

Comment: @Dev There is actually a little beauty to getting back to the original object. You should be able to get it by extending the chain with `$.siblings('.hlight')`. Because the original object should be the only object with that class, that will be what you get.

I am not sure what you mean by your first comment regarding CODE I.

Comment: Because of your `$(this).removeClass('hlight');` statement.. I understood the concept and further minimized code.. :)  `$searchBoxParent.on({
 mouseover: function() {
  $(this).addClass('hlight');
 },
 mouseout: function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hlight');
 },
 click: function() {
  $searchBox.val($(this).text()).focus();
  setCurrentlySearchedText();
  deleteSuggestionsDiv();
 }
},"#searchSuggest div");`

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `$this = $(this)` is not redundant, it minimizes performance reducing DOM queries by making `this` an object.

Here's one way to solve your problem using the `.on` functionality:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.SOMECLASS', function () {
    //code here
})
```

EDIT:
I can see that I also should have explained that you'll only need to make the `$this = $(this)` declaration one time. Once the object is declared the DOM object is no longer accessed rather the javascript/jQuery object, on which you can use functions like `$this.parent(...` etc.

You're correct that your code is currently making redundant declarations. Nest the declaration in the `.on` function, but outside/before the functions that will use the object.

Comment: It is redundant.. it look up `$(this)` every time in jQuery object whenever we encounter statement `$this = $(this);` Secondly i don't know why you wrote the second `$('body').on('click', '.SOMECLASS', function () {
    //code here
})` its totally out of context of question. :(

Comment: I want your attention towards this statement - `$this.parent().find(".hlight").removeClass('hlight');` can i do something regarding this?